# Convert Json file nested list of dicts to rows of dicts in Python

Tags: python, json, list, nested

I have a json file and I need to convert list of dicts to multiple rows of dicts.

**Example o code:**

```
{
"A": {
 "B": {
  "C": [
    {
    "1":"value_x",
    "2":"value_x",
    "3":"value_x"
   },
  {"1":"value_y",
   "2":"value_y",
    "3":"value_y"
   }
  ]}}}
```

**Ideal output:**

```
{"A_B_C_1":"value_x"},
{"A_B_C_2":"value_x"},
{"A_B_C_3":"value_x"},
{"A_B_C_1":"value_y"},
{"A_B_C_2":"value_y"},
{"A_B_C_3":"value_y"}
```

I tried to flatten json, but one row result is illegible

```
def flatten_json(nested_json):
    try:
        out = {}
        def flatten(x, name=''):
            if type(x) is dict:
                for a in x:
                    flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
            elif type(x) is list:
                i = 0
                while i > 0:
                    for a in x:
                        flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                        i += 1
            else:
                out[name[:-1]] = x
```

Comment: Your input and expected output aren't valid JSON. The keys are not quoted, and `{[1, 2, 3]}` is valid only in Python as a list in a set (which isn't a valid data type in JSON), and what is `{c0: 1, 2, 3}`?

Comment: Your "ideal output" is not a valid data structure (neither in JSON or Python). Please re-read your question and update the required output. And as @blhsing indicates, the input isn't valid either - is that actually what you're looking to process? Are you sure you should be accepting invalid JSON in your code?

Comment: this is a valid json of your data :{
"a":{
 "b": {
  "c0": [1, 2, 3],
  "c1": [1, 2, 3],
  "c2": [1, 2, 3]
}
}
}

Comment: the result that you want it is an valid format  are you sure  that you are looking for something like that

Comment: Yes , you’re right, The original input have doble quote for keys and values, I wrote the concept not real case. Sorry

Comment: So how can i help you

Comment: rewrite original input and output

Answer (score 0):

Here is another attempt using recursion to achieve your desired output. Keep in mind that the code below was made according to the sample data you provided:

```
import json

def flatten(data,outList,resultData):
    for key, value in data.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            outList.append(key)
            flatten(value,outList,resultData)
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            outList.append(key)
            for elem in value:
                for inner_key, inner_value in elem.items():
                    outList.append(inner_key)
                    final_key = '_'.join(outList)
                    resultData.append({final_key : inner_value})
                    outList = outList[:-1]
    return resultData

def showData(resultData):
    for elem in resultData:
        print(elem)

with open('data.json') as inFile:
    data = json.loads(inFile.read())
    resultData = flatten(data,[],[])
    showData(resultData)
```

The output will be:

```
{'A_B_C_1': 'value_x'}
{'A_B_C_2': 'value_x'}
{'A_B_C_3': 'value_x'}
{'A_B_C_1': 'value_y'}
{'A_B_C_2': 'value_y'}
{'A_B_C_3': 'value_y'}
```